# How to split memory between mapreducer and hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a machine with 24 G memory and want to run `hdfs`, `map-reducer` and `hbase` on them but I want to split the memory between the `map-reducer` and `hbase`.

I want hbase to use a maximum of 15G ram and map-reducer to get 8G max. What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration files you can specify how much each process is allowed to have.
HBase is controled by the hbase-env.sh
mapreduce is controlled by the mapred-site.xml

There are good comments in each of the file to help you locate the exact property you are looking for.

The most tricky one is the mapreduce: depending on how many slots you want to have you have to divide the maximum memory you are willing to give to mapreduce by the number of slots you make available on the machine.  So, if you only want one slot, you can set the max child memory to 8GB; 2 slots gives you 4GB; etc.

You can also set the child memory to be final in the mapred-site.xml file so that the tasks themselves can't override it.